# Segfault on ofstream::open() if defined outside of function

Tags: c++, linux, fstream, ofstream

I'm writing a little shared library to test some things via LD_PRELOAD and I want to write logs to a file.

The following code works:

```
void ctor() __attribute__((constructor));
void dtor() __attribute__((destructor));

void ctor() {
  std::ofstream log_file;
  log_file.open("/home/tristan/Test.log");
  log_file << "Log Stuff..." << std::endl;
  log_file.close();
}
```

This causes a Segfault:

```
void ctor() __attribute__((constructor));
void dtor() __attribute__((destructor));

std::ofstream log_file;

void ctor() {
  log_file.open("/home/tristan/Test.log");
  log_file << "Log Stuff..." << std::endl;
  log_file.close();
}
```

Why is that? Something to do with the constructor attribute perhaps?

My GCC flags are as follows:

```
gcc -fPIC -m64 -shared -lstdc++ -o Test.so *.cpp
```

Comment: Is there a reason that `log_file` shouldn't belong to the function `ctor`?

Comment: I was planning on using the log_file globally. Opening it in ctor, outputting in my other functions, and closing it dtor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the `__attribute__((constructor))`. The `ctor` function is called before global variable `std::ofstream log_file` is initialized and so causes the segfault.